# Minus operand after variable in java

Tags: java

I found this code,  but could not get what does the minus do here:

`numIterations–;`

```java
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder("testing");
int numIterations = text.length();

for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++) {
  System.out.print(text.charAt(i));
  if (someCondition()) {
    numIterations–;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think its `--`, rather than `-`, although even then I don't understand the logic of this program

Comment: This is the url with almost equivalent code in kotlin  :        
 https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/for-loop-with-dynamic-condition/57

Answer (score 4):

It causes a compiler error.

Probably whoever wrote the code meant `numIterations--;` (note double `-`), which subtracts one from the variable.